# How do i make a 5 letter username a requirement?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
username=input("input username= ")
to_deny = ["!", "?", " ", "/", ",", ".", "[", "]", "(", ")",]
if any([char in username for char in to_deny]):
    print("denied characters: ?, !, space(s), /, dots, [], ()")
    quit()
else:
    print("hello",username,"!")
```

How can I make it so that the username must contain exactly 5 letters?

Comment: `if len(username) != 5:`

Comment: Or `username=""; while len(username) != 5: username = input()`?

Comment: I'll try that too! @Chris

Comment: Your question don't really have anything to do with "username" in general.  What you should have asked is "how to find length of string in Python"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Questions should only explain **the question**, not discuss anything about you or your personal frustrations. I [edit]ed the question to show you how it is done.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```py
username=input("input username= ")
to_deny = "!? /,.[]()"
if any(char in username for char in to_deny):
    print("denied characters: ?, !, space(s), /, dots, [], ()")
    quit()
elif len(username) != 5:
    print("username must be at least 5 characters")
    quit()
else:
    print(f"hello {username}!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
if any([char in username for char in to_deny]):
    print("denied characters: ?, !, space(s), /, dots, [], ()")
    quit()
elif len(username) != 5:
    print("username must be 5 characters")
    quit()
else:
    print("hello",username,"!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use regex, it's really powerful and can be useful to know for harder requirements (e.g. : email validation, phone number validation, website validation)

```
import re

regex_condition = r"^[^!? \/,.[\]()]{5}$"
my_string = "aaaaa"

if (re.search(regex_condition, my_string)):
    print("String checked")
```

1. `^` mean start of the string
2. `[^!? \/,.[\]()]` mean a single character NOT in `!? \/,.[\]()`
3. `{5}` mean match the previous token (the single character not in the list) exactly 5 times
4. `$` mean end of the string

You can learn and train regex on https://regex101.com/